# i want to edit or remove in SocialEngine

Tags: php, ftp, socialengine

I have installed SocialEngine PHP 4.8.12 successfully and it works fine, but when I try to rename/edit/Chmod any file or folder inside directory : public_html/application/modules using Cpanel or FTP I see no changes and I get error :
FTP-ERROR
Response:   550 Could not change perms on Module.php: Operation not permitted.

Whats wrong and how can I fix thiss issue ?!

Thanks in advance

Comment: how did you install the application? do you have shell access to your server?

Comment: On what platform did you install it?

Comment: check if u have sudo permissions and try with sudo